How can I always pretty-print outputs in CIDER REPL and evaluation results?
I'm using CIDER on Emacs for Clojure development.
Whenever I execute the command cider-eval-sexp-at-point, I see the output in the Emacs mini-buffer. I can also see it in the *Messages* buffer (since everything displayed in the mini-buffer goes there).
Here are my settings in my init file:
(use-package cider
  :straight t
  :config
  (setq nrepl-log-messages t))

I would like to change it so that:

Everything printed in the REPL is always pretty-printed.
The output of cider-eval-sexp-at-point is pretty-printed in the REPL.

I tried:
(use-package cider
  :straight t
  :config
  (setq cider-use-overlays nil)
  (setq cider-repl-use-pretty-printing t)
  (setq cider-print-fn 'pprint))

But, it did not work. I am still seeing things as before the changes with mini-buffer showing the output of function calls.
How can I configure CIDER to achieve the desired behavior?
Note: I try to keep my config file reproducible with use-package declarative style. Relevant docs on Cider.

Divide and conquer: don't try to do everything at once. I would start by having the REPL output pretty printed (just set cider-repl-use-pretty-printing to t and forget the rest). Then start adding the others one-by-one to see what breaks things.
